# Changing the content of <p> in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change the context of a paragraph but I am unable to do so. Can any one suggest me, where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

1. A script element can load a script from an external `src` **or** load an inline script, not both. You need two script elements.
2. You can't modify the contents of an element before it exists in the DOM. Your script that calls `$` needs to be moved after the paragraph (or converted into a function and called after the element exists, e.g. with a `ready` or `load` event handler).

Answer (score 0):

Place the jQuery code inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... } );`, as in this example:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("p#myDiv").text("Hello World");
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Also end that `script` tag properly, but I guess that was just a copy/paste mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Document ready function

   $(function() {
       $('#myDiv').text('Hello World');
   });
```